# Animate movement around list

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate, css-transitions

I need to append an item into a list with easing transitions. Rather than have the others abruptly move into their new location on append, I need them to ease into their new positions.

```
<ul>
  <li id="1"/>
  <li id="2"/>
  <li id="3"/>
  <li id="4"/>
  <li id="5"/>
</ul>
```

Psuedocode `appendInMiddle`:

```
$('ul').appendInMiddle(<li/>)
```

Comment: Have you seen my answer ? Isn't it what you wanted ?

Answer (score 0):

I have set a css animation that adds a negative margin at the beginning, and then it removes it restoring the standard look: (plain JS used to insert the element, but you can use jQuery if you want to, just add the class to the new element)

```js
function add () {
    
    var ele = document.getElementById('2');
    var parent = ele.parentElement;
    var added = document.createElement ('li');
    added.innerHTML='new';
    added.className = 'add';
    parent.insertBefore (added, ele);

}
```

```css
.add {
    animation: grow 1s;
}

@keyframes grow {
    from {margin-bottom: -1em;}
    to {margin-bottom: 0em;}
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="1"/>
  <li id="2"/>
  <li id="3"/>
  <li id="4"/>
  <li id="5"/>
</ul>
<button onclick="add()">add</button>
```